# AWS NLB idle timeout to ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have client -> some company VIP -> NLB-> ALB -> host -> pod configuration, NLB has an idle timeout of 350secs and cannot be configured according to AWS Documentation.

However I have reports that take longer than that, and NLB is closing the connection. We already have ALB configured to 3600 idle timeout.

Is there a way to fix this and make NLB -> ALB connection to not timeout. AWS says that sending keep alive packets form target, but my NLB target is ALB which I can not control to send those packages, neither the company VIP thing in front of the NLB

My setup is created from EKS. NLB, ALB, and cluster are all created via kubernetes

Comment: Have you tried to reset the timeout with TCP keepalive packets ??

Comment: the setup is, client -> some company VIP -> NLB-> ALB -> host -> pod. neither VIP to NLB or NLB->ALB can be controlled to send those packets.